# Optimized updates of a grid-based particle system

Tags: java, performance, game

I've been working on a game somewhat similar to [this one](https://dan-ball.jp/en/javagame/dust/) for a little while now. My game is based around a 'board,' which is filled with different types of particles that react with one another and the environment. With every update of the screen, the board, and all of the particles within it have to be updated (moving, changing state, reacting to one another, producing other particles, destroying other particles, etc.). The 'board' is implemented in a class called `ParticleSystem`:

```
package main.java.engine;

import main.java.particle.particles.Particle;

import static main.java.engine.VelocitySystem.VCEL_W;

/**
 * In charge of holding and updating particles.
 */
public class ParticleSystem implements IParticleSystem {
    private final int width;
    private int count;
    private Particle[][] particles;

    public ParticleSystem(int width) {
        if (width <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("width should be greater than zero");

        this.width = width;
        this.count = 0;
        this.particles = new Particle[width][width];
    }

    /**
     * @return The width of this particle system.
     */
    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    /**
     * @return The number of non-null particles contained w/in this system.
     */
    public int getParticleCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void addParticle(Particle p) {
        if (p == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("particle to add should be non-null. " +
                "remove particles with removeParticle method.");

        int px = p.getX();
        int py = p.getY();

        if (isOutOfBounds(px, py)) return;
        particles[px][py] = p;
    }

    public void removeParticle(int x, int y) {
        if (isOutOfBounds(x, y)) return;
        particles[x][y] = null;
    }

    public Particle getParticle(int x, int y) {
        if (isOutOfBounds(x, y)) return null;
        return particles[x][y];
    }

    /**
     * @param x x position.
     * @param y y position.
     * @return The number of particles above the point (x,y) until the first empty spot.
     */
    @Override
    public int countParticlesAbove(int x, int y) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        if (isOutOfBounds(x, y)) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("(" + x + ", " + y + ")");
        int count = 0;

        y++;

        while (y < width && particles[x][y] != null) {
            count++;
            y++;
        }

        return count;
    }

    /**
     * @param x x position to start at.
     * @param y y position to start at.
     * @return The number of particles below the starting (x, y) position.
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if the given starting (x, y) position is out of bounds.
     */
    @Override
    public int countParticlesBelow(int x, int y) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        if (isOutOfBounds(x, y)) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("(" + x + ", " + y + ")");
        int count = 0;

        y--;

        while (y >= 0 && particles[x][y] != null) {
            count++;
            y--;
        }

        return count;
    }

    public void move(Particle p, float dx, float dy) {
        float f_px = p.getExactX();
        float f_py = p.getExactY();
        float f_new_px = f_px + dx;
        float f_new_py = f_py + dy;

        int i_px = (int) f_px;
        int i_py = (int) f_py;
        int i_new_px = (int) f_new_px;
        int i_new_py = (int) f_new_py;

        if (isOutOfBounds(i_new_px, i_new_py)) return;
        if (particles[i_new_px][i_new_py] != p && particles[i_new_px][i_new_py] != null) return;

        p.setX(f_new_px);
        p.setY(f_new_py);
        particles[i_px][i_py] = null;
        particles[i_new_px][i_new_py] = p;
    }

    public void run() {
        Particle p;
        float vx, vy;

        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                p = particles[i][j];

                if (p == null || p.ticked) continue;
                p.update(this);
                p.ticked = true;
            }
        }

        markUnticked();
    }

    /**
     * Revert the system to its initial state.
     */
    public void clear() {
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                particles[i][j] = null;
            }
        }
    }

    private void markUnticked() {
        count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                if (particles[i][j] != null) {
                    particles[i][j].ticked = false;
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isOutOfBounds(int x, int y) {
        return (x < 0 || x >= width || y < 0 || y >= width);
    }
}
```

A `Particle`'s update method may look something like:

```
public void update(ParticleSystem p) {
    this.dy += this.properties.getGravity();

    p.move(this, dx, dy);

    dx = 0;
    dy = 0;
}
```

In the future, update methods may become more complicated -- they may involve looking at neighboring elements, removing elements, or adding new ones.

I've tried implementing the `ParticleSystem` with data structures other than a 2D array, but have found it to have significantly better performance than both the `ArrayList` and `HashMap` classes. It seems that some kind of multithreading might go a long way here, but I'm not really sure how I could do that and still ensure that Particles updated properly.

I've two main questions that I'd like answered:

1. How can I improve the performance of this algorithm?
2. How can I improve the structure of what I've written?

### **Edit**

Answers to some questions asked:

- The board is currently 300*300 particles wide.
- The number of expected particles could really be anywhere between 0 and 300^2, though I'd say it averages between 1/3 and 1/2 full.
- Iterating one 300*300 board, when full, takes ~0.003 seconds.
- I'm not aiming for any *particular* speed, I just wanted to see if it could be sped up.

I've not come up with too many Particle movement algorithms yet. However, here are some plausible examples:
**Water:**

```
public void update(ParticleSystem p) {
    // move the water back and forth at random
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
        dx -= 1;
    } else {
        dx += 1;
    }

    p.move(this, dx, dy + this.properties.getGravity());
}
```

**Ice:**

```
public void update(ParticleSystem p) {
    for (int i = this.x - 1; i <= this.x + 1; i++) {
        for (int j = this.y - 1; j <= this.y + 1; j++) {
            if (p.getParticle(i, j).getProperties().getID() == Water_ID) {
                if (Math.random < 0.01) {
                    p.addParticle(new Particle(ICE_ID, i, j));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Some rather obvious stuff...

## General

- You're violating the Java "braces everywhere" style the same way I do. What should I say? :D
- Shortcuts like `p` are usually frown upon; I find them fine for short-lived local variables, but less acceptable for parameters. Especially with `p` used for both `Particle` and `ParticleSystem`.
- A null check should throw an NPE rather than IAE (IIRC according to J. Bloch).
- Your naming `getExactX` vs. `setX` sounds inconsistent.
- `markUnticked` has a second job of computing `count`, which is strange. You could update count whenever it changes instead.
- Your `width` is also `height`, so maybe `size` would be better.

Your code is pretty clear, but `count` (although private) could use some comment (or a more verbose name). I'm unsure, how you decide to throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException` or not.

You definitely should switch warnings on. `run` declares unused `vx` and `vy`.

## Optimizations

> I've tried implementing the `ParticleSystem` with data structures other than a 2D array, but have found it to have significantly better performance than both the `ArrayList` and `HashMap` classes.

This surely depends on the density of your data. With 1 particle on a 1000x1000 board, a sparse structure would surely be faster. Arrays are the fastest as long as they're used to a non-negligible fraction and you need no search.

A 1D array would probably be even faster as long as you can avoid division (in bounds checks). Using a power of two size can make it fast at the cost of some wasted memory. This is a low-level optimization, which may complicate your code for minor gain.

Your `move` using floating point sounds rather complicated. I guess, you could speed it up by using fixed point instead (work with `dx<<10` instead of `dx`). Again, this is a low-level optimization, even worse than the 1D array.

> It seems that some kind of multithreading might go a long way here, but I'm not really sure how I could do that and still ensure that Particles updated properly.

Multithreading is rather complicated and the gain is limited by the number of cores you have. Given you current code, I guess, it should not be hard to split the computation into horizontal stripes (vertical doesn't sound good because of `countParticlesAbove` and below). There's also some horizontal interaction due to moving particles, but only local. I'd go for multithreading only after examining other possibilities.

There's one simple high-level optimization possible: In case your particle typically move only a fraction of the pixel size (i.e., dx, dy << 1), then you may want to replace ticked by a variable counting how long it takes to leave the current pixel. This may interact with accelerating or alike, but may lead to smoother movement for equal computation overhead.

---

So, I can't give you any good advice at the moment. Let us know

- how big is your board
- how many particles are there
- how long does an iteration take
- how much faster it should get

Also give us more Particle rules, ideally exactly the code you want to optimize. Some particle kinds are probably slower to compute than others. Maybe you're wasting time in scanning through nearly empty arrays? We don't know.

I'll add more if you do (Note that adding details to reviewed code is OK, improving it on the fly is not).

## Addendum after the update

Do not use `Math.random()` in anything but throwaway code. Oftentimes you need reproducibility and you can get it with using `random.nextDouble()` instead. You can get reproducibility by seeding the random and randomness otherwise.

For 50% booleans, there's `nextBoolean()`, for n%, there's `random.nextInt(100) < n`. Using double is fine, too.

---

```
 p.getParticle(i, j).getProperties().getID() == Water_ID
```

This looks too complicated for something as important as the particle type. Having general `properties` in the particle sound flexible, but maybe particles should have no properties besides their type and coordinates (as you probably can't show more, anyway). I'd never call something non-unique for a particle "ID", "type" sounds better. Using an enum, there's no need for an "ID" of the "type". The test should probably be as simple as

```
 p.getParticle(i, j).getType() == Particle.Type.WATER
```

Answer (score 2):

(You won't believe how long I was clicking around the app you linked, that thing is somewhat satisfying... )

This is very interesting! If you got a github repo, I'd be happy to play around with it. If not, I'd be happy if you would make a github repo =)

#### Performance in general

Well, to improve performance for future requirements, which are not specified, can often results in a step backwards: Requirements can change or are not required anymore. Then, you're sitting on code wich is implemented for requirements, which are, well, not required. "By definition", more code makes your app slower. That's why I argue, that measuring is the most important thing to do, when it comes improving performance, because sometimes you get the opposite. And: The more flexibility you have, the less I'd invest time for potential performance problems. Less flexible would be stuff like, geographical aspects (e.g. where is the data center located) or scalability aspects (the software must perform the same for customers who want to analyze gigabytes of data as it would for customers who want to analayze peta bytes of data, just by adding more servers) or any given restrictions, like bandwidth.

#### FPS

One thing I want to mention: Since you visually display your data, you should have a component which renders the particles. So all your calculations must be finished within 1/'Amount of FPS you want to render' seconds. If you haven't finished the calculations, just skip a frame.

And: At least decouple rendering from calculation, if you haven't done that yet, it shouldn't be too hard to achieve and it should improve performance (which should be verified/measured).

#### multi threading

That's usually a thing I try to avoid. Because,... well, let me phrase it like that: If you want to solve a problem using multi threading, you might solve the problem, but you will get at least one other problem :P

Most of the particles move themselves. When I'm thinking about two particles with gravitational force, they both influence each other's direction and speed. Now, you could either calculate the new position of one particle, set the position, and calculate the new position of the other particle, using the newly set positions of the first particle, *or* you could calculate the positions, and set them at the end. I *think* this way you could at least multithread the calculations of the next position. And the outcome of the new positions should be always the same.

Other interactions, like spawning or destroying particles, I'm not really sure. If I'm looking at the app you linked: If a ice particle touches a water particle, and a 'bomb' particle touches a ice particle: Which should go first? Because: The bomb particle could destroy the ice particle, and at the same time, a ice particle could turn a water particle into ice, even though it got destroyed at the same time. If you analyze it, or if you define a rule set yourself, you might find particle types which can be calculated parallel.

Hope this helps,

slowy

Comment: I like the comment that you make about performance. It makes sense that I should try to implement the other features first before fretting about it. Your suggestion about how I could multithread the movement is also an interesting one. Thanks! (i'll try to get a github repo set up)

Comment: https://github.com/treeman1111/Particles